# Will a motor scooter leak when tilted at 45°

Tags: honda, motorcycle, moped

My family is moving and the movers loaded our Honda Ruckus into the truck with the front wheel raised to make a 45° angle. Could this cause any fluids to leak?

Comment: Wild guess: since you can corner with a motorcycle at 45 degree angle to the side, it is designed to be tiltable to the side. I'm not sure it follows from this that you can raise the front wheel to make a 45 degree angle -- certainly you can't drive up that steep hill. However, if you can tilt it to the side, it is likely it could be tilted as much in other directions.

Comment: @juhist Intuitive...but not correct. Bikes are designed to allow leaning for purposes of not dragging the frame or muffler on the ground when the machine is cornering and leaning over. A single-track vehicle (scooter, motorcycle) leans as it travels around corners; the lean is the result of the machine finding equilibrium between gravity and centrifugal force. The machine and its loads (rider, fuel, liquids in tanks or reservoirs) feel these two forces as a single force downward through the machine, just the same as though the machine were upright.

Answer (score 1):

No fluids leaked and the Honda ruckus running just fine!